# Who modifies affected components in an agile environment?

Tags: build-process, continuous-integration, agile

In a continuous integration, agile environment, if I make a change in class A (e.g. change attribute names) which I have created and have been working on, that affects class B, which "belongs" to someone else, who modifies class B whenever I want to check in my change? Me or the class' B owner?

I suppose is more agile if I modify it, so that I don't have to notify other people, but at the same time, people working on it are more aware of the impact of modifying it...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In an agile environment, class B (like all classes) belongs to *the team*.  We call this [Shared Code Ownership](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/CodeOwnership.html).  You should check in working code; if that means you need to adjust class B to conform to the changes you make to class A - adjust!  Better yet, pair.

Comment: +1 for emphasis on "Shared Code Ownership"

Comment: +2 for "Better yet, pair" - which often leads to Shared Code Ownership.

Answer (score 3):

1. "Individuals and interactions over process and tools." Communicate the change upfront with the other people impacted. Unless the code is trivial, you may not understand the full impact of the change. Even if you do, you owe it to your other teammates to keep them informed.
2. "Don't break the build." Checking code in that you know will break the build is not a good idea. Once you have communicated with the others that are impacted, work with them to get the code changes completed. Attempt to get the code changes checked in so at least the nightly build is not broken.

Just my opinion....

Bob

Comment: +1 for mentioning "Don't break the build." It is surprising how many people think being agile means doing "fast development", even if it means they breaking builds in the process!!

Answer (score 1):

> who modifies class B whenever I want to check in my change? Me or the class' B owner?

With no disrespect, I think your question is so basic that it clearly suggests that you do not have even basic understanding of what being Agile means. Well, maybe that's why you asked this question.

Here are my suggestions:

1. In this kind of situation you really should walk up to the other developer who might be impacted by your change and have a quick face to face conversation about this, this quick conversation may lead to you guys pair programming to make sure the build does not break, and no one gets affected.
2. Please read all the Agile Principles again, and write down what you understand from each one of it. Implement those principles in your day to day development life. This is the only way to become Agile. There is no certification or book to refer to, to make someone Agile magically. Being Agile has to be self realized, hence practice them daily till they become a habit.

So the "Information" is conveyed using the most effective method i.e. f2f conversation. The problem is solved on the basis of the collective responsibility principle, most ideal way to fix it is pair programming.

Reference:
Agile principle 
"The most efficient and effective method of 
conveying information to and within a development 
team is face-to-face conversation."

Also a general Agile Guideline from the manifesto:
"Responding to change over following a plan"

Comment: I absolutely stand by what I said. What is more important than +1 here is transparency and honesty. Stack Overflow suggests this: "Be honest", which is very important because if we don't, then everyone would just get up votes and sugar coated comments and more so since this q&a is operating within the SO framework, I'll agreeably go by that. Again, honestly speaking, your question reflects less basic knowledge of Agile. If you do not agree, prove it (with honesty). BTW you are very welcome for finding my references valuable. I would be more than happy to help further, if needed. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

### Agile includes team code ownership, communication

As @Carl Manaster said, the code belongs to the team. And as @rcravens suggests, agile is about communication. Have a quick meeting with the author of B and let them know your proposed changed to be sure you understand your impact. If it's complex, pair with B's author on the change. When the change is complete, if you think it might affect other developers on the team, call a brief team meeting and let them know of the change.

### By the way, how's your design?

Your question may aslo be revealing a design issue - A and B might be too tightly coupled. After your tests work and you've implemented the change, I suggest that you examine your code and see if something needs refactoring. (Remember, TDD is [Red/Green/Refactor](http://jamesshore.com/Blog/Red-Green-Refactor.html)) In particular, if changing class A means you have to change class B, then you might not be following the [Single Responsibility Principle (SRP)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) arm of [SOLID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid_%28object-oriented_design%29) practice.